# i need to void dot(.) form user key press is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my jquery it is avoid all the symbols and alphabet but it allow a dot (.) i don't know why someone help me please. . .

```
 $('.Number').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode;

    keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 27 || keycode == 9 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
    else {

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have better to use a regex for that kind of check:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbLYb/)

```
$('.Number').keypress(function (event) {
    if(!/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) return false;
});
```

Comment: Same type i need to do for alphabet and i restricted number for that how i change this code

Answer (score 1):

According to: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes the correct keycode for . (period) is 190 (or 110), and you have not added this to your list.

Note that browser implementations (and thus results) may vary and I have no idea the effect of regional keyboard settings on these keycodes.

Answer (score 1):

Because you *haven't added the keycode for decimal point.*

`110` for `.` for full stop
`190` for decimal point